# How can I ensure that hyperlinks for shared documents always open directly in the app?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, ms-word, office365, ms-office

The organization I work for has recently migrated its document storage management to SharePoint. When you share a document with others, it sends you an email with a link to the shared document. This link always opens in the browser version of the app (e.g., Word, Excel, or PowerPoint). How can I change this to open these links directly in the app instead of the browser version?

I've already tried several potential solutions, but I haven't found the right one for me. Many people suggest going to one of the Office apps, such as Word. From there, navigating to the advanced tab and looking for the "link handling" option. However, I can't seem to locate this option. The only related one I can find is "File Open Preference," and I've already switched that from Browser to Desktop. Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve the issue with hyperlinks.

[Screenshot "File Open Preference"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHsnH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't set Shared Links to open directly in Client Application. But we can add   `ms-word:ofe|u|` in front of the shared link to prompt user to open in client application.

For example:`ms-word:ofe|u|https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/Karley12/EVK-2pQAWipFvSIq6QMfpmwBP-s_g8ON2GWEwFIBAwE-4A?e=XoB6lS`
[image]